# Unclear where I'm going wrong while reciving JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I've spent nearly 3 hours on stack exchange and on google trying to piece together various information. So, this is what I have on guess.php

**PHP**

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
get_rating($cleanMovie);
json_encode(array($id));
```

The get_rating function works just fine.

Now I want to post some data into this php form and get the string out of it, but since I was getting the whole HTML code when I was trying to use dataType: string. I read it would be better to use json and hence I made the above modifications instead of a simple "`print $id;`"

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "guess.php",
data: { m: "Avenger"},
dataType: "json",
success: function(d) {
       alert(d);
    }
});
```

Nothing is being printed. I want it to just print the string. Moreover, it is possible to get rid of all the JSON and work with just string that is seen on the PHP page?

**How do I handle this output?**

I'm missing out many concepts in better.Please clarify!

Thanks,
Sai

Comment: You have semi-colon `;` at the end of `dataType: "json";` replace it with comma`,`

Comment: That was just a typo. Still doesnt work.

Comment: if you go to `guess.php?m=Avenger` in your browser what is the output.  In addition where is `$id` coming from? what is its value? I think you need to display more of your php code.

Comment: It gives a string as I want it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you should `echo` the response:

```
- json_encode(array($id));
+ echo json_encode(array($id));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When i echo it, it changes the header!

Comment: Excuse me? It won’t :)

Comment: try to change the header after doing echo